# SQL syntax error but copied from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have an SQL query which i copied from MYSQL and i removed the quotations however, it doesnt seem to work.

```
 conn = connect();
           selectStatement = "UPDATE student SET Item ? = ?, Type ? = ? WHERE ID = ?";
           System.out.println(selectStatement);
           if(conn != null)
           {
                preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectStatement);       
                preparedStatement.setString(2, id);
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, location);
                preparedStatement.setInt(3, location);
                preparedStatement.setString(4, type);
                preparedStatement.setString(5, userId);
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();        
                return true;
```

I am not sure why it does not work as the exception thrown is this

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 = 'sad', Type 1 = 'asd' WHERE ID = 'student1'' at line 1

Comment: Sql statement should be: selectStatement = "UPDATE student SET Item=?, Type= ? WHERE ID = ?";

Comment: Can you please tell what are the column names in student table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end this worked.

```
          conn = connect();
          selectStatement = "UPDATE student SET `Item " + location + "` = ? , `Type " + location + "` = ? WHERE ID = ?";
          System.out.println(selectStatement);
          if(conn != null)
          {
               preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectStatement);       
               preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
               preparedStatement.setString(2, type);
               preparedStatement.setString(3, userId);
               preparedStatement.executeUpdate();        
               return true;
          }
```

Comment: lol okay. This is so odd. Generally it is a bad idea to have spaces in column names anyway.

Comment: Please tell me that `location` and `type` are never being entered by the user. Can I input a location of `=1 where 0; drop student; --`